# Should the tag-excerpt edit page show a preview?

Tags: feature-request, edits, tag-excerpt

Editing a tag-excerpt recently I used white space (a blank line) to separate two sentences.  Of course the white space is ignored so the end result was two sentences jammed together.

The mistake was mine, I should have paid more attention to the "no markdown" reminder.  But a preview of the suggested text would have helped draw my attention to the unintended effect. This could be especially useful for people who don't edit tags frequently.